# What's wrong in this integral

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

Where's the mistake in this solution? $$\int \tan^3x\sec^2xdx = \int \frac{\sin^3x}{\cos^5x}dx=\int\frac{\sin x(1-\cos²x)}{\cos^5x}dx=\int\frac{u^2-1}{u^5}du$$$$=\frac{1}{4u^4}-\frac{1}{2u^2}+C=\frac{1}{4\cos^4x}-\frac{1}{2\cos^2x}+C$$ for $ \cos x=u \to du=-\sin xdx$.
 I also tried doing $$\int \tan^3x\sec^2xdx = \int u^3du=\frac{u^4}{4}+C=\frac{\tan^4x}{4}+C$$ for $ tgx=u \to du=\sec^2xdx$

Please help!

Comment: Both your answers are correct; the 2 functions just differ by a constant.

Comment: Have you tried diffentiating your 2 answers to see if one or the other are the right (or wrong) answers? Have you tried subtracting and simplifying your two answers? If you do one or the other of these actions, you will find that both your answers are good (... up to a constant).

Comment: Thanks! I didn't tried it yet. As the exercise's answer was the second one, i tried again thinking that mine was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{4\cos^4x}-\frac{1}{2\cos^2x} +\frac{1}{4}
&= \frac{1-2\cos^2 x+\cos^4x}{4\cos^4 x}\\
&= \frac{(\cos^2x-1)^2}{4\cos^4x}\\ 
&= \frac{(-\sin^2x )^2}{4\cos^4x}\\
&= \frac{\tan^4x}{4} 
\end{align}